# Regexp replacement: difference between \([[:digit:]]+\) and ([[:digit:]]+)

Tags: replace, regular-expressions

With `M-x replace-regexp`, I found that both  `\([[:digit:]]+\)` and `([[:digit:]]+)` will match `(123)`, and not one without parentheses, But the first will replace `123` and the second `(123)`. I wonder why the difference?

Comment: `\([[:digit:]]+\)` should definitely match `123`. Doesn't it for you?

Comment: seems match (123) not 123, but replace 123 inside (123). or am i wrong?

Comment: `\([[:digit:]]+\)` matches any number of digits. So it matches `123` and it also matches the numbers in `(123)`. In both cases it replaces only the numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In emacs regular expressions (unlike most regexp engines), `\(` and `\)` are group delimiters, while `(` and `)` match litteral brackets.

So: `\([[:digit:]]+\)` matches one digit or more, that is here `123`, and makes it a group. That means that for example, `\([[:digit:]]+\)?` would match either `123` or some empty string, and that you can use `\1` (assuming it is your only group) for `123` in the replacement text.

On the other hand, `([[:digit:]]+)` matches an opening bracket, one digit or more, then a closing bracket, so it will match `(123)`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is emacs the only one that uses this convention? Or does it follow some standard which also applies to other engines?

Comment: For example, `sed` does use a similar convention by default, but it doesn't force you to use this implementation (you can choose the regexp style that you prefer through command line flags). With emacs, you have no built-in alternative.

Comment: Does emacs regex follow POSIX standard?

Comment: No. POSIX regexes use unescaped brackets as group delimiters, escaped brackets are litteral brackets. The behavior of braces and escaped braces is similarly swapped.

Comment: by brackets [], you wanted to mean (), right?

Comment: @Tim For an overview of common regexp syntaxes, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) on [unix.se]. T. Verron: there are two POSIX standards, BRE and ERE (Emacs is neither: it is sort of in between).

Comment: If I remember correctly `(` and `)` are brackets too in Britain.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, english is not my native language, yes, I mean `(`. I call `[` square brackets. `:)`

Comment: @Gilles Ah, indeed, my bad. I never really used BRE and I thought ERE were just an extension. So, I can't edit that comment now, but to make it clear: my previous comment was about POSIX ERE (`grep -E` or `sed -r`). BRE use the same convention for brackets (parentheses) and braces, but emacs' regex syntax contain a lot of non-BRE constructs (`?`, `+`...), and most of these are made of non-escaped characters.